# Use of CSI-2 Based cameras on Jetson TX-2 for mapping

Tags: ros, camera-driver, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Im planning to develop a platform with Nvidia Tx-2 and 5 cameras. I'm trying to choose a camera and 'm really confused. I was thinking of choosing CSI-2 cameras as TX-2 has 6 CSI-2 ports, but I wasn't sure how hard it is going to be to integrate the CSI-2 camera on to ROS. Or should I stick with USB cameras and get a carrier board with USB hub on it. Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261168/use-of-csi-2-based-cameras-on-jetson-tx-2-for-mapping/) by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

6 MIPI CSI-2 Cameras support for Jetson TX1 from e-con systems may suit your purpose. The latest release supports 6 CSI- 2 cameras with TX2 also.

https://www.e-consystems.com/blog/camera/6-mipi-csi-2-cameras-support-for-jetson-tx1/
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1018955/?comment=5188095

---

Originally posted by [mathews](https://answers.ros.org/users/28651/mathews/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0